# Android Recycler view using Grid Layout Manager equal spacing not working

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

Recycler view item decoration not equally spaced when span count is odd. When I set even span, the spacing looks equal but when set odd span count the middle column spacing is little bit disturbed. How to resolve this issue? The code is:

```
final int spacing = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.recycler_spacing);
// apply spacing
recyclerView.setPadding(spacing, spacing, spacing, spacing);
recyclerView.setClipToPadding(false);
recyclerView.setClipChildren(false);
recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new RecyclerView.ItemDecoration() {
@Override
public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
    outRect.set(spacing, spacing, spacing, spacing);
}
});
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add margin in your row xml for equal spacing in your recyclerview. Its the easy way to add equal spacing between your list items.

Comment: What? Left, Right margins will become double as span count increases. That's not the solution for equal spacing

Comment: no use margin="10dp" like this in your  parent layout of your row this will now increases by items.

Comment: like this. <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp">
    </RelativeLayout>

Comment: This answer helped a lot when using constraint dimension ratio in recycler view. This link is also useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43973185/constraintlayout-unable-to-scale-image-to-fit-a-ratio-in-recyclerview